# Negative binomial (significant but exp(x)=1)

Tags: statistical-significance, negative-binomial-distribution

I am looking at the influence of likes of Facebook of various websites on some dependent variable with values ranging from zero to thousands. So the number of likes can be zero for certain website and can also be more than a thousand. I suspect the appropriate analysis is negative binomial. But I am not 100% sure.:) Also when I performed negative binomial analysis using SPSS, it showed a significant impact. However, the beta is very close to zero and hence its IRR is 1. I am not sure what went wrong.

**Code for SPSS**

```
* Generalized Linear Models.
GENLIN outcome WITH fbk linkedin
  /MODEL fbk linkedin INTERCEPT=YES
 DISTRIBUTION=NEGBIN(1) LINK=LOG
  /CRITERIA METHOD=FISHER(1) SCALE=1 COVB=MODEL MAXITERATIONS=100 MAXSTEPHALVING=5
    PCONVERGE=1E-006(ABSOLUTE) SINGULAR=1E-012 ANALYSISTYPE=3(WALD) CILEVEL=95 CITYPE=WALD
    LIKELIHOOD=FULL
  /MISSING CLASSMISSING=EXCLUDE
  /PRINT CPS DESCRIPTIVES MODELINFO FIT SUMMARY SOLUTION.
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Parameter   B   Std. Error  95% Wald Confidence Test    Lower   Upper   Wald Chi-Square df  Sig.
(Intercept) 12.682  0.1461  12.396  12.968  7536.173    1   0.000

fbk          **3.746E-05**  1.4166E-05  9.694E-06   6.522E-05   6.992   1   0.008

linkedin    0.002   0.0002  0.002   0.002   74.305  1   0.000
```

Sample size is 98. As can be seen from the above output, the facebook likes has a strong significant impact. However the IRR is 1.

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, your models, & your goals here? Can you paste in a sample of your data? Can you paste in your model output? I'm not sure there's enough information right now to say anything.

Comment: Please edit that information into the body of your question. We don't want it buried in the comments. How many cases are there in your data (what is N)?

Comment: The coefficient for fbk is per unit increase. If you want it in a more sensible range try expressing fbk in thousands.